# запись координат выделенных объектов с помощью opencv

Tags: python, opencv

мой код:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


img_rgb = cv.imread('test.png')
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv.imread('arrows\\up.png', 0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv.imwrite('res.png', img_rgb)
```

он отлично работает обводит три объекта на картинке которые мне нужно получить, но при попытки получить координаты этих трех объектов у меня возникли проблемы, я не могу понять где лежат эти координаты len(loc[0]) показывает 36 элемента, что не может быть так как на картинке обведено всего лишь 3 объекта на картинке, как мне получить координаты только трех тех объектов на картинке которые выделил мне opencv

Comment: А что именно там за данные (покажите hex)? вероятно это и есть 36 байт (или несколько многобайтных чисел)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все верно, дело в том, что res>=threshold  выдает  не одиночные точки, а небольшие области, в районах максимумов. Как вариант, можно использовать центроиды этих связных областей.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv.imread('test.png')
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv.imread('arrows\\up.png', 0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
bw=res>threshold
centroids=cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(np.uint8(bw))[3]
centroids=np.int32(centroids[1:,:])
for pt in centroids:
    cv.rectangle(img_rgb, (pt[0], pt[1]), (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv.imwrite('res.png', img_rgb)
```